# Sorting Algorithm Proof

Tags: algorithms, solution-verification, sorting

*Hydrosort* is a sorting algorithm. Below is the pseudocode.

```
*/A is arrary to sort, i = start index, j = end index */

    Hydrosort(A, i, j):                 // Let T(n) be the time to find where n = j-1+1

      n = j – i + 1                              O(1)
      if (n < 10) {                              O(1)
        sort A[i…j] by insertion-sort            O(n^2) //insertion sort = O(n^2) worst-case
        return                                   O(1)
      }
      m1 = i + 3 * n / 4                         O(1)
      m2 = i + n / 4                             O(1)
      Hydrosort(A, i, m1)                        T(n/2)
      Hydrosort(A, m2, j)                        T(n/2)
      Hydrosort(A, i, m1)                        T(n/2)
```

How would I prove that Hydrosort(A, 1, n) correctly sorts an array A of n elements?

Answer (score 0):

By induction on the number of elements.  Assuming you believe insertion sort works, if $n \lt 10$ Hydrosort works because it just calls insertion sort.  That is the base case.  Now if $n \ge 10$ you partition the problem into three pieces.  If none of them is $10$ or larger Hydrosort will work because each piece will work.  How large can $n$ be so that no piece is $10$ or larger?  Now you know Hydrosort works up to that $n$.  Now if the partition results in all pieces of that $n$ or less you know Hydrosort works.  You have to justify that if I start with a large $N$ of things to sort, the pieces will eventually get down to less than $10$.  You can do this by showing that at each step the maximum allowable $n$ is multiplied by some number greater than $1$.  Can you do that?

Comment: "...you partition the problem into three pieces.
If none of them is 10 or larger Hydrosort will work because each piece will work."
This is not necessarily true in general, that if the three pieces are individually sorted,
then the whole thing is sorted too.
This needs to be proved, that such combination of partition
of the array 
and sorting parts results in a sorted array.

Comment: It is true you need to prove that.  The fact that the three pieces overlap will drive all the large elements to the end.  Note that each subsort handles $3/4$ of the elements, so if the largest starts out first the first sort puts it $3/4$ of the way up and the middle sort puts it at the end.  The timing for each subsort is $T(3n/4)$

Answer (score 0):

One helpful fact could be
useful for
both numerical (for small $n$)
and theoretical proofs that 
sorting algorithm works correctly:
if it is able to sort all $2^n$ 
binary combinations of $n$ bits,
then it also will sort any 
sequence of $n$ numbers.